# How to add validation only to an associated table in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I have an address table in rails:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  validates :street, :city
            presence: { allow_blank: false }
end
```

the table is associated with several tables and I added validation to prevent street and city from being null or "", but I wanted this validation to only run on the associated table user

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address
  validates_associated :address
end
```

User has a belongs_to for address, and would not like to put a belongs_to inside the address. How do I make address validations only work when the table is user?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your requirements. You only want to validate the presence of street and city when the address is associated with a user? Otherwise it could be blank?

Comment: That's right, because the address table is associated with other tables, but I just wanted validation to run when it was the user's address

Comment: You can't use two belongs_to on opposite sides of an association anyways. The inverse should be a has_one/has_many.

Comment: One way to do this would be to to use single table inheritance and create a UserAddress model that contains the validations.

Answer (score 0):

When you only want to validate the presence of `street` and `city` when there is a `user` or at least one user associated with the `address` then I would add a `if` condition to the validate definition, like this:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users

  validates :street, :city
            presence: { allow_blank: false },
            if: Proc.new { |a| a.users.present? }
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :address

  validates_associated :address
end
```